Is the Philips Hue Bridge a per-person or per-household device?
As I've asked at the Hue Essentials Discourse forum (yet received no response):

My brother and I use Hue lights in our rooms in a shared residence. The rest of my family doesn’t (yet). Should we each own a bridge associated with our personal accounts to control our lights, or should we utilize a shared bridge, because they are designed to be residence-wide?
I ask because if the 2nd option is correct, whether that would scale to the rest of the entire residence is not evident.


Per household.
Local discovery of the hub by the app is done on the LAN.
There is expected to be a level of trust between users with access to the local network

Would using one per person be a problem, in that case? As in, might they interfere with each other? I don't want to have to configure VLANs.

I cannot see a reason to have separate Hue networks within the same household. You'll pair each bulb to just one of them, which would mean that half of your lights can be controlled with one application and the other half with the other. It sounds like a usability nightmare, with no obvious benefits.

If you are trying to stop your brother controlling your lights? This won't work, as anybody with local network access can control both bridges, as I said their is an expectation of trust for anybody with local network access.
